# Converting sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize to boundingRectWidth

Tags: ios

So i just cam across one old iOS Project and following line it says its deprecated:

```
CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:self.stringLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300)];
```

it says i should use boundingRectWidth but if i try with

```
CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:self.stringLabel.font boundingRectWidth:CGSizeMake(200, 300)];
```

I am trying to upgrade deploy target to 9.0 because one of libs is build for 7.0 + thats why i realy must update this. It says it does not exists, any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out following code. You can pass dictionary of attributes while calling boundingRectWithSize. In your case dictionary will contain Font attribute.

```
CGRect stringSize = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.stringLabel.font} context:nil];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with the following code:-

```
    CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 21)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font-Name" size:fontSize]} context:nil];
```

Note:-
If you need to set text in width, then set its width to any number i.e. 1000 in example code and set height to the required dimension. Same If you want to set your text in height, then set height to random number and width equal to required dimension.